# Groovy(/Java): Lock on unique values of a variable?

Tags: java, groovy

I have some code in a groovy script where if a graph for a certain name does not exist, I create a new instance of it.

```
if (!graphMap.contains(graphName)) {
  newGraph = createGraph(graphName)
  graphMap.put(graphName, newGraph)
}
```

The problem is this is running in parallel and the createGraph() call takes ~60 seconds, so sometimes I'll create 2 instances of the graph and only save 1 of them to my map (because they'll both see the map doesn't contain the name and then create it). It's my understanding that I can lock on the map to avoid this problem, like so:

```
synchronized(graphMap) {
  if (!graphMap.contains(graphName)) {
    newGraph = createGraph(graphName)
    graphMap.put(graphName, newGraph)
  }
}
```

But the problem with this is that creating a graph can take a while, and I want to be able to create graphs for several different names at the same time. That is to say, if I get 3 concurrent requests to create graphs for **foo**, **foo**, and **bar**, I want to create **foo** and **bar** concurrently but not create the 2nd **foo**. Is it possible for me to synchronize not on the map, but instead on specific name values?

Comment: One solution to this is to use [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), however I'm not sure which object you would want to lock on for this.

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution is to:

- Use a [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) as the type of `graphMap` so that you know it can handle concurrent additions (of different keys).
- Synchronize on `graphName` after [`intern`ing it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--):

```java
graphName = graphName.intern();
synchronized(graphName) {
  if (!graphMap.contains(graphName)) {
    newGraph = createGraph(graphName)
    graphMap.put(graphName, newGraph)
  }
}
```

If you have two `String`s with the same contents but in different `String` objects, `synchronized` won't work properly, as it will synchronize on different objects and neither will block the other.

However, when `intern()` is given a `String` with certain contents, it always returns the same object every time for those contents, so synchronizing on **that** object will work properly.

This allows you to block only on the contents of that particular `graphName` rather than the whole `graphMap`, allowing more concurrency. It also prevents any wasted work of adding a value for that key twice.

Comment: Great, clean solution. Thanks!